# What is the correct and portable (Clang/GCC) modifier for uint16_t in sscanf?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, clang

I get a warning message when I try to compile this code 
`sscanf(value, "%h" PRIu16 "B", &packet_size)`
 with Clang 600.0.57 (OS X).

```
warning: format specifies type 'unsigned char *' but the argument has type 'uint16_t *'
      (aka 'unsigned short *') [-Wformat]
    if (sscanf(value, "%h" PRIu16 "B", &packet_size) == 1) {
                       ~~~~            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

But if I remove the modifier "h", then I get the following error with GCC 4.8.3 (Scientific Linux 7).

```
warning: format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int*’, but argument 3 has type ‘uint16_t* {aka short unsigned int*}’ [-Wformat=]
     if (sscanf(value, "%" PRIu16 "B", &packet_size) == 1) {

                                                   ^
```

What is the correct and portable modifier for uint16_t* in sscanf?

**=== Added more self-explaining example below ===**

**test.c**

```
#ifndef __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS 1
#endif
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char* str = "16 bits";
  uint16_t u16;
  sscanf(str, "%h" PRIu16 " bits", &u16); // Clang warning
  sscanf(str, "%" PRIu16 " bits", &u16); // GCC warning
  sscanf(str, "%" SCNu16 " bits", &u16); // OK for both compilers

  printf("%" PRIu16 " bits\n", u16);

  return 0;
}
```

**Clang warning**

```
$ clang test.c -Wall -Wextra
test.c:10:36: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned char *' but the argument
      has type 'uint16_t *' (aka 'unsigned short *') [-Wformat]
  sscanf(str, "%h" PRIu16 " bits", &u16); // Clang warning
               ~~~~                ^~~~
1 warning generated.
```

**GCC warning**

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:11:3: warning: format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int *’, but argument 3 has type ‘uint16_t *’ [-Wformat=]
   sscanf(str, "%" PRIu16 " bits", &u16); // GCC warning
   ^
```

Comment: It's `SCNsN` for `scanf()`. Use: `sscanf(value, "%"SCNu16"B", &packet_size)`, and remember to `#include <inttypes.h>`

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/ says you want `sscanf(sourcestring,"%hu",&uint16Value)`.  I don't know what `PRIu16` is expanding to, but maybe it's expanding to something that's tells `sscanf` to look for a `unsigned char*`? (or maybe the compiler doesn't do very well emitting this warning with macros involved?)

Comment: @RussSchultz cplusplus.com says no such thing. You can't assume `typedef unsigned short int uint16_t`. The portable way to use `<stdint.h>` with the `printf` and `scanf` functions is to use the constants provided in `<inttypes.h>`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @EOF remarked in their comment, `fscanf` and `fprintf` each have their own macros for this.

In the [final C99 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), §7.8.1 clause 4 and 5 (page 199) says that `<inttypes.h>` shall define the following macros:

> 4. The `fscanf` macros for signed integers are:
>
>    SCNd*N* SCNdLEAST*N* SCNdFAST*N* SCNdMAX SCNdPTR
>      SCNi*N* SCNiLEAST*N* SCNiFAST*N* SCNiMAX SCNiPTR
> 5. The `fscanf` macros for unsigned integers are:
>
>    SCNo*N* SCNoLEAST*N* SCNoFAST*N* SCNoMAX SCNoPTR
>      SCNu*N* SCNuLEAST*N* SCNuFAST*N* SCNuMAX SCNuPTR
>      SCNx*N* SCNxLEAST*N* SCNxFAST*N* SCNxMAX SCNxPTR

If you want to read `uint16_t` as decimal numbers with `fscanf`, you must use `SCNu16`.

Example:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    uint16_t input;

    int items = scanf("fetch %" SCNu16 " bits", &input);

    if (items == 1) {
        printf("I'm busy, go fetch those %" PRIu16 " bits yourself.\n", input);
    } else {
        printf("I don't understand what you're saying.\n")
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest updating your answer to show *how* to use these macros. The usage pattern isn't obvious.

Comment: @Rhymoid Thanks a lot. I added a better example in my question.